Pc does not accept any input after setting up controller
After i setup a pdp xbox controller using steam, i installed the extra functionality (don't realy now the name). To make it work, i needed to restart my pc. Now my pc does not accept any input but my bios still does. I am still able to connect to wifi with an external wifi adapter, so it is really only the input that does not work.
The pc i'm talking about is a dell optiplex 9020.
The operating system is Windows 10.
I tried multiple keyboards, mouses and the controller on every usb port. I also configured an arduino micro as a keyboard, but again did not work (it did on other pc's). I ran on-board diagnostics through the bios, which said everything was fine. I also accidentally went in the windows recovery, which accepted input, and tried startup recovery, which again resulted in nothing. Now i am not able to get there anymore, but if i get there, i may be able to boot in safe mode. Maybe that could work? I think steam may have updated my drivers in the wrong way. The problem is not with the controller, cause I actually configured it on another computer yesterday. The computer belonged to a school, but I have never had any problems with it (with programming, gaming, booting, etc.)
I could finally get back in windows recovery by inserting a windows 7 recovery cd, starting it, and NOT pressing a button to begin the program. I sometimes needed to retry it. I booted into safe mode, but I could still not use any hid. I afterwards tried using a usb hub, but it still did not work. Then I thought about using the command prompt from windows recovery to rollback the driver(s), but none of the commands I found online
devcon(.exe)
pnputil(.exe)
((%WindowsDir%\system32\)mmc )devmgmt.exe

worked and I also did not have the driver's name.

I used my windows 7 disk to reinstall windows, from there I could go ahead and update to a newer version but I like windows 7 better than those newer versions (I would consider windows 10 to run newer games / apps). Too bad about my files and apps but the most important ones I had backed up.
